# What are the bars placed outside of windows called?

Tags: meaning, words

Apartments and buildings have bars placed on them outside of the windows and I wanted to know what they are called. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean something like this, it's called [手【て】すり](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%89%8B%E6%91%BA) or specifically 窓手すり (for preventing an accidental fall):

[image]

格子 looks like this (for preventing an escape or invasion):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

「格子{こうし}」 would be the generic word.

Use 「鉄格子{てつごうし}」 if they are made of iron.

Use  「アルミ格子{ごうし}」 if they are made of aluminum.